# Showing axioms of modal propositional logic are independent

Tags: logic, modal-logic

S5 is defined as the system extended from system K with the S4 schema $\Box \phi \rightarrow \Box \Box \phi$ and the S5 schema $\phi \rightarrow \Box \Diamond \phi$.

I'm trying to show that the axiom schema $\Box \phi \rightarrow \phi$ is independent from the rest of the axioms of S5. i.e. that S5 does not prove all instances of the schema $\Box \phi \rightarrow \phi$.

I have soundness of S5. And in classical logic to show independence of axioms, you would just create a countermodel and then apply the contrapositive of soundness to show a formula is not provable. But in this case, doesn't every S5 model satisfy $\Box \phi \rightarrow \phi$?

Comment: Just to clarify terminology: System K means propositional logic + necessitation and K: $\square(P\to Q)\to (\square P\to \square Q)$. Usually we define S5 = System K + T + 4 + B, where T is $\square P\to P$, 4 is $\square P\to \square\square P$, and B is $P\to \square\lozenge P$ (in the question, you left T out of your definition of S5). Now define S5$-$ to be System K + 4 + B. Am I correct that you are trying to show that S5$-$ does not prove T?

Comment: (Of course every S5 model satisfies T, since T is an axiom in S5. What you want to show is that there is an S5$-$ model that does not satisfy T. Right?)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming my clarification in the comments is what you intended:

Consider a Kripke frame with a single world $w$ and no accessibility ($w$ is not acessible from $w$). Then at $w$, $\square \varphi$ holds vacuously for all $\varphi$. It follows that all instances of 4 and B are valid on this frame. But T is not valid on this frame. For example, suppose $P$ does not hold at $w$. Then since $\square P$ holds at $w$, $\square P\to P$ is false at $w$.

Comment: But isn't this frame not symmetric since $w$ is not accessible from $w$? So wouldn't this frame not be an S5 frame?

Comment: @MattAdamBarnes This frame is symmetric and transitive but not reflexive. Indeed it is not an S5 frame, since T is not valid! But it is what I'm calling an S5$-$ frame, i.e. it satisfies all the axioms of S5 except for T.

Comment: Right, I should have written reflexive. Also, in the frame you've given, the 5 schema holds trivially. But how does this establish independence? So the frame demonstrates that there exists some Kripke frame that makes K,B,4,5 all true, but makes an instance of $\Box P \rightarrow P$ false. But how can we apply the soundness theorem since this frame is only transitive and symmetric. Are we applying the soundness theorem of the K system?

Comment: @MattAdamBarnes Yes, exactly. Apply soundness of System K for arbitrary Kripke frames.

Comment: But wouldn't this only show that $\Box P \rightarrow P$ is not provable from system K?

Comment: @MattAdamBarnes Suppose for contradiction that there is a proof of $\square P\rightarrow P$ in System K from instances of axioms B, 4, and 5. Then (by soundness of System K) in any Kripke frame in which these instances of B, 4, and 5 are valid, $\square P\rightarrow P$ is valid. But we have a counterexample to that. Therefore there is no proof of $\square P\rightarrow P$ from B, 4, and 5.